# Django Allow User to Add a New Item to a List

Tags: python, django

I have a todo website that would allow users to create a list, and have them create events and specify which list to put it in. Right now, I have a Reminder model that contains a list with a General option:

```
class Reminder(models.Model):
    remind_types = [('Regular', 'Regular'), ('Long Term', 'Long Term')]
    remind_lists = [('General','General')]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()  
    remind_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True) 
    parent_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type_of_remind = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=remind_types, default='Regular')
    remind_list = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=remind_lists, default='General')
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I was thinking of  creating a form that would have the user input a title, and add the title to remind_list. I would have a menu that allows the user to view reminders based on a specific list, and have reminders passed through like this:

```
from .models import remind_lists
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)
    context = {
        'events': ToDoItem.objects.filter(parent_user=user),
        'reminders': Reminder.objects.filter(parent_user=user, type_of_remind='Regular'),
        'long_term_reminders': Reminder.objects.filter(parent_user=user, type_of_remind='Long Term'), 

    }
    for list_menu_name in remind_lists:
        context[list_menu_name] = Reminder.objects.filter(parent_user=user, type_of_remind='Long Term', remind_list=list_menu_name)
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

But I'm kind of lost on how to do this. I was thinking of creating a model with just a CharField, but I don't know how to add just the name into the list of remind_lists. I'm quite new to Django, so I apologize if its a simple answer.

Comment: Hi, @Silent Beast. Could you please provide your template and other models? Then I could reproduce it here.

Comment: I just need to know an approach on how to do this, but a specific example would also help. I reproduced part of my website here: https://repl.it/repls/NiceCarefreePixels. I only put in my reminders as I'm testing the new list feature on them.

Comment: Thanks, @Silent Beast. I'm testing it now.

Comment: @Eliakin Costa- Sorry, just realized how awful my reproduce was, nothing works because theres no option for pip install on repl and a lot of my forms come from other packages. All I need is an approach on how to do this.